# Keep Azure WCF http relay alive

Tags: azure-servicebusrelay

I have set up a relay successfully on an existing service by adding an endpoint to my local WCF service

endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="https://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/brokers" binding="basicHttpRelayBinding" contract="Services.WebServices.IBrokerService" behaviorConfiguration="clients" bindingConfiguration="HttpRelayConfiguration"/>
```

behaviour:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="clients">
                <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
                    <tokenProvider>
                        <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="dsfsdfsdfsdfds"/>
                    </tokenProvider>
                </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
```

binding:

```
<basicHttpRelayBinding>
            <binding name="HttpRelayConfiguration"/>                
        </basicHttpRelayBinding>
```

Its working great but if I don't access the underlying WCF service through the browser for a while azure doesn't pick up the relay.

What is the easiest way to ensure that the relay is always available when the underlying WCF service is up and running?

Answer (score 1):

First, the "[Azure Service bus Relay](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay.md)" is now referenced as [Azure Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-what-is-it) ([repository GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay)), based on [Azure Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/).

For your WCF service remains continuously available, you might consider implementing a keep-alive mechanism. This can be achieved by periodically sending requests to an existing endpoint on the underlying WCF service, such as the WSDL, rather than adding a separate "ping" method. This is based on the observation that merely accessing the WCF service keeps the Azure Relay alive.

For testing, create a simple client that will call this "`Ping`" method at regular intervals, using for instance a [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0):

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Timers;

namespace KeepAliveClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(60000); // Set interval to 60,000 milliseconds (1 minute)
            timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            timer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit the application.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a proxy to your WCF service
                ChannelFactory<Services.WebServices.IBrokerService> factory = 
                    new ChannelFactory<Services.WebServices.IBrokerService>("YourWSDLorEndpointHere");

                Services.WebServices.IBrokerService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

                // Call the Ping method
                string response = proxy.Ping();

                if (response == "Alive")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is alive.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected response.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do replace `"YourWSDLorEndpointHere"` with the actual WSDL or another endpoint URL of your WCF service.

---

Alternatively, you can set up an [Azure Automation Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types) to accomplish the same task. The Runbook can contain a PowerShell script to access the WSDL or another endpoint at regular intervals.

Within your Azure Automation account, create a new [PowerShell Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types?tabs=lps51%2Cpy27#powershell-runbooks).

```
# Define the URI to the WSDL or another endpoint on the WCF service
$uri = "https://YourWSDLorEndpointHere"

# Make the web request
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET

# Check the response
if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Service is alive."
} else {
    Write-Host "Service is not responding as expected."
}
```

Once your Runbook is tested and published, schedule it to run at regular intervals to keep your relay alive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - I was hoping that I wouldn't have to implement some kind of polling mechanism and that it could possibly be configured in IIS. Is there are reason you would want to poll the relay endpoint and not the endpoint on the underlying service? If I load the underlying service in the browser then it "announces" to the relay that it exists so if I'm creating something to poll maybe it makes more sense to just create something to load the WSDL every 60 seconds which would mean we don't need to explicitly create a ping method?

Comment: @woggles " Is there are reason you would want to poll the relay endpoint and not the endpoint on the underlying service?": good point. I have amend and simplified the answer accordingly. No need to explicitly create a ping method.